# Theme not working after database transfer (Theme key "0" not found)

Tags: 7

I have copied the database of my production site to my dev site and my theme is not working anymore (on the dev). The content (nodes) is not exactly the same, but theme folder is.

All the information in the CSS files is still displaying but the settings in `admin/appearance/settings/corporateclean` (UI for basic colors) have no effect anymore.

The logs show the following warning: `Theme key "0" not found.`

I have tried flusing the caches, de-activate cache pages, CSS aggregation without success. I had the issue in the past and copying all the files fixed it but it's a brute force fix and I'd like to understand what happens. I am 100% sure the theme directory is up to date, so some other files may be messing. Any idea?

Comment: Are both sites running the same drupal version?

Comment: Yes, they both run 7.14

Comment: Perhaps something has happend to your registry, try to rebuild it, read more here http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but my registry was fine. I finally found the problem: the path to the custom logo was wrong, and when I fixed that it worked